# Nested collection mapping fails with automapper

Tags: c#, collections, nested, mapping, automapper

Somehow the mapping fails with the error message:

---

> **One or more errors occurred. (The following member on Data.Shop cannot be mapped:
> Images
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Data.Shop.**

---

After having spent some time tinkering with it and searching for a solution on the official documentation + SO, I feel like I either messed up / forgot with a particular call in the profile, or need to resort to creating a custom map.. What do you guys think?

Configuration code that I used:

- Entities

```
public class Shop
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Specialty Specialty { get; set; } = new Specialty();

    public Address Address { get; set; } = new Address();

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; } = new List<Image>();

    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();

    public List<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; } = new List<Promotion>();
}
```

```
public class Image
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

- DTOs

```
public class ShopDto
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short Plz { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public List<ImageDto> Images { get; set; } = new List<ImageDto>();

    public List<TagDto> Tags { get; set; } = new List<TagDto>();

    public List<PromotionDto> Promotions { get; set; } = new List<PromotionDto>();
}
```

```
public class ImageDto
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

- Profile code

```
CreateMap<Image, ImageDto>();
CreateMap<Shop, ShopDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.City, member => member.MapFrom(source => source.Address.City))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Plz, member => member.MapFrom(source => source.Address.Plz))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Street, member => member.MapFrom(source => source.Address.Street))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HouseNumber, member => member.MapFrom(source => source.Address.HouseNumber))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Images, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Images))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(src => src.Id, dest => dest.Ignore())
            .ForMember(src => src.Promotions, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Promotions))
            .ForMember(src => src.Tags, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Tags))
            .ForMember(src => src.Images, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Images))
            .ForPath(src => src.Specialty.Name, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Specialty))
            .ForPath(src => src.Address.City, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.City))
            .ForPath(src => src.Address.Plz, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Plz))
            .ForPath(src => src.Address.Street, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Street))
            .ForPath(src => src.Address.HouseNumber, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.HouseNumber));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a mapping from `Shop` to `ShopDto` but appear to be attempting to map `ShopDto` to `Shop`. You need define mappings in both directions or swap the template arguments. Of course you also need a mapping from `ImageDto` to `Image`.

Additionally you can remove this part:

```
.ForMember(src => src.Images, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => src.Images))
```

AutoMapper is smart enough to map collections if it has a mapping for the collection element type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now two separate maps: CreateMap<Shop, ShopDto>() and         CreateMap<ShopDto, Shop>() without Images collection mapping. The exact same error still occurs when  config.AssertConfigurationIsValid() is called.

Comment: You also need a mapping frem ImageDto to Image.

Comment: It indeed solved the problem, and I understand the need to map in both directions now.  thank you very much :) have a nice evening